# counting the number of loop runs

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following loop structure:

for $i_1=1$ to $m$
for $i_2=i_1$ to $m$
$\vdots$
for $i_n=i_{n-1}$ to $m$

Of course, all indices $i_k$ are integers, and $m$ and $n$ are also positive integers.

How can I count how many times the inner loop will run?

Comment: Can you do it for $n=1$? Can you use the answer for $n=1$ to get an answer for $n=2$? Can you use the answer for $n=2$ to get an answer for $n=3$? Can you find a pattern in the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each loop is characterized by the $n$-tuple $(i_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$, where
$$1\leq i_1\leq i_2\leq\ldots\leq i_n\leq m\ .$$
It can be encoded as a sequence of $n$ zeros and $m-1$ ones in the following way: The $n$ zeros symbolize the $n$ $i$'s in increasing order. Write $i_1-1$ ones in front of the first zero, for $2\leq k\leq n$ write $i_k-i_{k-1}$ ones between the $(k-1)$th and the $k$th zero,  and write $m-i_n$ ones after the last zero.

Now there are $\displaystyle{{n+m-1 \choose m-1}}$ such sequences.

Comment: Very nice. Note that the list of $i$'s can be found by taking for every $0$ in the sequence one more than the sum of the digits to its left (which might explain the particular way $0$ and $1$ are used). The "one more" here is due to the fact that the loops start at $1$ rather than at the (for me) more usual starting value $0$ (and then of course ending _just before_ $m$).

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in which it really helps to look at some small examples or to start with the simplest version and work up (or both!). The simplest version is $n=0$, which isn’t very interesting. The next simplest is $n=1$, which is also pretty trivial. The first interesting case is $n=2$, but it turns out to be helpful to have looked at some variants of the $n=1$ case first.

Suppose that there’s one instruction $I$ inside the nest of loops. If there are no loops, $I$ is executed once. If there’s one loop running from $i$ to $m$, $I$ is executed $m-i+1$ times. In particular, if there’s one loop running from $1$ to $m$, it’s executed $m$ times.

Now suppose that there are two loops. The inner loop runs from $i_1$ to $m$ for each value of $i_1$ from $1$ to $m$. Thus, $I$ is executed $m-i_1+1$ times for each value of $i_1$ from $1$ to $m$, for a total of

$$\sum_{i_1=1}^m(m-i_1+1)=\sum_{k=1}^mk=\binom{m+1}2\;.$$

How many times is $I$ executed if the outer loop runs from $j$ to $m$ instead of from $1$ to $m$? That would be

$$\sum_{i_1=j}^m(m-i_1+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{m-j+1}k=\binom{m-j+2}2\;.$$

Now suppose that there are three loops. The second loop runs from $i_1$ to $m$ for each value of $i_1$ from $1$ to $m$, so $I$ is executed a grand total of

$$\sum_{i_1=1}^m\binom{m-i_1+2}2\tag{1}$$ times. You’ve probably seen an identity involving binomial coefficents that will let you simplify $(1)$ to a single binomial coefficient.

You may now already be able to generalize to get the result for arbitrary $n$; if not, try repeating the argument to derive the result for $n=4$. Once you have the result, you’ll need to prove it by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Since the loop variables are called $i_1,\ldots,i_n$, there are clearly $n$ nested loops.

This is probably not what you were after, but it *is* the answer, as per "What You Ask For Is What You Get". (Well actually you asked "How can I count ..."; I'll spare you the answer to *that*.)